# -bash: !": event not found when trying to run Java program

Tags: java, bash, terminal

```
[Running Java 1.7.0_51 on MacOSX]
```

Hey there,

This is frustrating me, as I've just successfully finished a piece of work I was supposed to finish in Java. However I'm getting some errors, when I run the code, for example, 
if I compile it and use: `java MyCode "Hello World!"`

I get the error: `-bash: !": event not found`

However, if I use single quotes like 'Hello World!', the program runs without any issues, or if the exclamation mark is not on the end if using the double quotes still.

I know this might not be directly a coding question, but I wasn't too sure, so I hope someone who may have had issues when running something similar, knows about this.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @fge - Bad guess.  What he has encountered is the bash shell's history expansion feature ... when running `java` from a bash shell prompt.  It is not a java issue at all.  He would have gotten the same error message by running `echo "Hello World!"` ...

Comment: You can turn off history expansion with `set +H`, re-enable it with `set -H`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right way to run your code from BASH is indeed by using single quotes:

```
java MyCode 'Hello World!'
```

In double quotes shell expands the quoted string and tries to find an event from history following `!` mark.

Comment: Alright. This was just an assessed piece of work, so I was worried if this was an issue, I'd get zero. They'll know this already then I suppose?

Thanks!

Comment: @zahz - If they don't then everyone will get zero.  Does that seem likely to you?

Comment: Sorry for my newbieness lol. I genuinely didn't know this. Thanks guys, will mark as best answer.

Comment: @zahz Don't worry; it's a consequence of how `bash` works, not anything to do with your code. `java MyCode "Hello World!"` works as expected from the `dash` shell, for example, because that shell does not have history expansion.